# how to remove file in local storage after send email in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, email, fputcsv

```
$email = $this->subject($this->registrationBatch->retrieve()->emailSubject());
foreach($attachments as $file){
    $email->attach($file)
}
return $email;
```

how to unlink $file after send email ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code for sending the email.

Comment: FIle is stored in public folder or in storage folder?

Comment: yup , file in storage folder

Comment: Then you can do this: `Storage::delete($path)`; Remember to give permission to the storage folder. And also check if you `$path` is giving you correct path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using deleteDirectory. example :

```html
$email = $this->subject($this->registrationBatch->retrieve()->emailSubject());
   foreach($attachments as $file){
           if($email->attach($file)){
                 $dir = '../storage/email/';
                 File::deleteDirectory($dir, true); // will delete all file or folder in folder email
           }
   }
return $email;
```